# Getting messages within 5 minutes from a specific ID and timestamp MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm building a chat app retrieving chat history when a certain chat is expanded but i want a function or functions that can help me get chats that are 5 minutes within each other and are sent by the same user let's say given this table below

| id | message | msg_owner_id | msg_reciever | msg_time | msg_type | seen | seen_time | note(not part of table) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hey | 20 | 6 | 10:42:51 | interchats | 0 |  | <----- 20 sent to 6 |
| 2 | hi | 20 | 6 | 10:43:20 | interchats | 0 |  | <------20 sent to 20 |
| 3 | am fine | 20 | 6 | 10:44:11 | interchats | 0 |  | <------20 sends to 6 again |
| 4 | mannnn | 6 | 20 | 10:45:02 | interchats | 0 |  | <-- 6 replies to 20 |
| 5 | mannnn | 20 | 11 | 10:53:02 | interchats | 0 |  | <-- 20 sends to 11 |

I have used the following code however some values are missing

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), DATE_FORMAT(msg_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), 
    id as ID, msg_owner_id as MSG_OWNER, msg_reciever as MSG_RECEIVER,
    message as MESSAGE 
FROM chats WHERE msg_time >= :msg_time - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND id >= :id 
GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2
```

let's say we need to start from id 1 and timestamp 10:42:51, how do I select all the chats sent within a 5 minutes interval from ID 1 and timestamp 10:42:52

Desired result should be:

the following IDs returned 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Please post your schema and  sample data as well

Comment: Also show the desired results, please.

Comment: Desired results should be IDs 1,2 and 3 only as they are the only ones within a five minutes interval from ID 1